# How to allow quoted whitespace in xtext

Tags: xtext

Creates myDSL grammar from Terminals

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"
```

Starting point, contains list of lines

```
Model: 
    lines+=LINE*;
```

Each line optionaly start with LABEL and then with keywords

```
LINE: 
    LABEL? outTest=DIRECTIVES;

//Line may start with only label with comma separated strings   
LABEL: 
    inputs+=MYSTRING  (',' inputs+=MYSTRING )*;

//Different supported keyword directives
DIRECTIVES : 
    WITHOUT_OPERANDS | WITH_MYSTRING| WITH_ONLY_MYSTRING;

//Directive for END tag
WITHOUT_OPERANDS: 
    tag=('END') (',')? (inputs+=MYSTRING)*;

//Directive for BEGIN tag
WITH_MYSTRING: 
    tag=('BEGIN') (inputs+=MYSTRING)* (',' inputs+=MYSTRING)*;

// Directive for PRINT tag
WITH_ONLY_MYSTRING: 
    tag=('PRINT') inputs+=MYSTRING*;

//Each string may or maynot contain quotes with empty string
MYSTRING hidden(WS):
    (UNQUOTED|QUOTED)+;

//Terminal String for match quoted string including empty one
terminal QUOTED:
    "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"    
;

//Terminal string matching all other 
terminal UNQUOTED:
    ('A'..'Z'|'a'..'z'|'_' |'0'..'9'|'-'|'#'|'='|'?'|'!'| '$'|'@'|"/"| '(' | ')'|'+'|'<'|'>'|'.'|"'"|"\\"|'"'|'*')*
;
```

This grammar work for string having white spaces in single quotes. But it has lot of Error/Warnings

warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:309:3: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:309:3: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:361:3: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:361:3: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:438:3: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:438:3: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:479:2: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 2, 3
As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:479:2: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 3
As a result, alternative(s) 3 were disabled for that input
error(208): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/parser/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:491:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_INT
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:257:33: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:257:33: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:549:45: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:549:45: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:604:42: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:604:42: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:738:47: Decision can match input such as "RULE_QUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
warning(200): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:738:47: Decision can match input such as "RULE_UNQUOTED" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
error(208): ../org.xtext.example.mydsl.ide/src-gen/org/xtext/example/mydsl/ide/contentassist/antlr/internal/InternalMyDsl.g:930:1: The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_INT
8287 [main] INFO  text.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator  - Generating common infrastructure

I have tried your updated grammar, but still it does not work.

Input Text:         BEGIN ABC'       '                   123457

Got error: no viable alternative at character ''

Input Text: PRINT    ABC'        ' abc

Got Error: extraneous input '\r\n' expecting EOF

Input Text:

BEGIN ABC=12,def=34,ghij                   123456

```
    xyx=123,abc=345                    000001
```

Got error: no viable alternative at input '\r\n\r\n'

All warnings were gone , except

error(208): The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_INT

error(208): The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: RULE_INT

Comment: what should be allowed inside quotes?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Christian. Inside quotes can be any characters including special one and whitespaces. e.g Welcome'To ', Welcome'  ', Welcome'To /hi $ ' etc

Answer (score 0):

did you consider to use two terminal rules and one datatype rule e.g.

```
//Terminal string          
STRING_OPERANDS hidden():
    (UNQUOTED|QUOTED)+
;

//maybe needs adoption
terminal QUOTED:
    "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"    
;

terminal UNQUOTED:
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '*' | "/" | "\\" | '(' | ')' | '$' | '=')*
;
```

or updated

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl2.MyDsl hidden(WS, ML_COMMENT, SL_COMMENT)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl2/MyDsl"

Model: 
    NL? lines+=LINE (NL lines+=LINE)* NL?;  

LINE: 
    label=LABEL? outTest=DIRECTIVES;

//Line may start with only label with comma separated strings   
LABEL: 
    inputs+=MYSTRING  (',' inputs+=MYSTRING )*;

//Different supported keyword directives
DIRECTIVES : 
    WITHOUT_OPERANDS | WITH_MYSTRING| WITH_ONLY_MYSTRING;

//Directive for END tag
WITHOUT_OPERANDS: 
    tag=('END') (',')? (inputs+=MYSTRING)*;

//Directive for BEGIN tag
WITH_MYSTRING: 
    tag=('BEGIN') (inputs+=MYSTRING)* (',' inputs+=MYSTRING)*;

// Directive for PRINT tag
WITH_ONLY_MYSTRING: 
    tag=('PRINT') inputs+=MYSTRING*;

//Each string may or maynot contain quotes with empty string
MYSTRING hidden(WS):
    ->(UNQUOTED|QUOTED)+;

//Terminal String for match quoted string including empty one
terminal QUOTED:
    "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'"    
;

//Terminal string matching all other 
//Terminal string matching all other 
terminal UNQUOTED:
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '*' | "/" | "\\" | '(' | ')' | '$' | '=')*
;



terminal ML_COMMENT : '/*' -> '*/';
terminal SL_COMMENT : '//' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;

terminal WS         : (' '|'\t')+;

terminal NL         : ('\r'|'\n')+;

terminal ANY_OTHER: .;
```